Missing dirt near hatch/house foundation
My house is missing dirt below the hatch entrance to the basement. It has disappeared slowly (over a long period of time), but it's now much more visible, I assume because we've had a lot of rain recently. (please check attached pictures). Below the hatch is where most of the dirt has disappeared (no photo because camera doesn't really pick it up).
I wanted to know if this is a serious issue or if I'm able to just fill it up without issues, and if that is the case, what should I use? Dirt? Sand?
Any help/guidance is very appreciated
Here are some pictures of what I'm talking about






please use the picture icon to add the images to your post, instead of adding links

the dirt is probably not missing ... it just settled

We need more context here.  You have some areas of missing soil on the camera side of your plastic lawn edging.  Looks to me more like erosion than settling.  That soil probably went the same place as the soil under your basement hatch.

The issue is that your hatch presents an inverted slope. There's no reason the soil would stay attached to it. Any settling at all and you have a gap. Unless the soil got wet enough to flow back against the concrete, this is inevitable. The good news is that the poured or cast concrete structure probably doesn't rely on support from the soil at all.
Fill it with whatever you have on hand, or just shove what's there tight and forget about it. You could try a loose sand to help keep it attached to the concrete, but even that may not work forever.

Yes it doesn't seem to be relying on it. So there shouldn't be any concern with the house's foundation right?
Is there any benefit of filling it with sand vs dirt?

I explained a potential benefit of sand. Otherwise it doesn't much matter. "Dirt" (organic soil) decomposes and shrinks, so it's less effective in maintaining volume.

Could also use a flowable fill—basically a loose concrete or mortar.  OP, do you know if your house has a foundation drain tile?

Any masonry product will have the same outcome, and now you have hard debris to deal with.
